# How to use two styles for the same listings language?

Tags: listings, options

At the moment I have two global options defined for my listings language: `color` and `monochrome` (I have bundled the language as a package and so these are package options). However, now I find that I would like to use the `monochrome` option for inline listings and the `color` option for multiple line listings.

I scanned through the listings package documentation and it seems like it might be possible to accomplish this functionality using dialects, however, I am not sure that it is the most semantically correct way of approaching the solution.

Here are my mwe files for the way it works right now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[fancyvrb]{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %for " quote
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[color]{mweisabelle}

\begin{document}



 \begin{lstlisting}[language=Isar, mathescape = true]{}   
assume "a \<rightarrow> b"
 \end{lstlisting}
 
 This statement should be black \Icode!assume!.
\end{document}
```

And package

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{isabella}[for easy Isabelle syntax]

\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{verbatim}
\RequirePackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
\RequirePackage[fancyvrb]{listings}
\RequirePackage{textcomp} %for ' quote
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} %for " quote
\RequirePackage{stmaryrd} % for rbrakk
\RequirePackage{upquote}

%% black and white option
\DeclareOption{monochrome}{
\definecolor{NULL}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{KEYWORD}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
}

%% colour option
\DeclareOption{color}{
\definecolor{NULL}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{KEYWORD}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,1}
}

\ExecuteOptions{monochrome, document}

\ProcessOptions\relax

      
\lstdefinelanguage{Isar}%
{    keywords=[1]{
        assume,obtain,show,fix
    },
        keywordstyle=[1]\color{KEYWORD}\bfseries,
            stringstyle=\color{black},
      moredelim = [s][stringstyle]{"}{"},
        literate=
                {\\<not>}{{$\neg$}}1 {\\<times>}{{$×$}}1   
                {\\<rightarrow>}{{$\rightarrow\ $}}1%
  }[keywords,comments,strings]%

% useful defaults
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\sffamily
}
\newcommand{\Icode}{\lstinline[{language=Isar}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that it is possible to edit the keyword style within the inline listing command declaration, e.g.

```
\newcommand{\Icode}{\lstinline[{language=Isar,keywordstyle=[1]\color{black}]}
```

If it is set to black this overwrites the previous colour. Thus the inline listings (or whichever individual listings I want) can have different text colour or style. Since this does not use the `monochrome` option this is perhaps not the most general solution but it suits my  original purpose.

Comment: Nice. Would be even nicer if you‘d add an example to your answer.